# Electronics (IC) reliability in aerospace engineering

Tags: integrated-circuit, reliability

This question was asked to me by a colleague earlier that day :

For how much operating time does an IC has to be qualified in the aerospace sector ?

My guess was about fifty years, but are there any standards that precisely define this time duration ?

Comment: Similar question to this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197054/optoisolator-reliability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aerospace equipment reliability is usually specified by the aircraft manufacturer when they set the requirements for a particular piece of equipment.

MTBF values of 50,000 to 100,000 hours (given a particular operating environment) are not uncommon for a box, which is ultimately what the aircraft manufacturer cares about as if a box fails, the box will be replaced.

This brings up the concept of a [Line Replaceable Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-replaceable_unit) (LRU) and a [Shop Replaceable Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shop-replaceable_unit).

The actual operating environment drives what can be achieved.

If a box is in a relatively benign environment (maximum temperatures below 55C in normal operation), it is not difficult to achieve very high reliability values; if it is hanging off the edge of a wing (such as a [wing hardpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardpoint)), things become more difficult.

When calculating reliability, it is usual to use [MIL-HBK-217](http://www.sre.org/pubs/Mil-Hdbk-217F.pdf) to build up a complete picture based on the parts proposed for a particular PCB, and the box level reliability calculated from the individual PCB level numbers.

The [failure rate of the devices](http://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/124041-calculating-reliability-using-fit-mttf-arrhenius-htol-model) in question is an input to the [failure prediction](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59774/what-are-fits-and-how-they-used-in-reliability-calculations), if it is available.

In terms of longevity of the kit, assuming no refresh has been made (true for older aircraft), I know that kit is still being repaired that was designed over 50 years ago. The actual box is not expected to last for 50 years of continuous operation without repair.